# SQL CASE mixes up my grouping

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, case

The problem situates itself at the 4th line of the SELECT statement: `CASE WHEN ct.TransactionReason=622 THEN ABS(ct.netquantity) ELSE c.RealNetWeight END AS NetWeight`

When I add this line to the statement, my grouping will change. Instead of returning one line it now gives me back the amount of lines of different `c.realnetweight`. 
Problem is that I only want to return one line. Sort of like a coalesce that when there is a `ct.transactionreason = 622`, it should give me `ABS(ct.netquantity)`, otherwise the `c.realnetweight`.  Code can be found beneath, suggestions would be very helpful. Thanks.

```
   SELECT   CASE WHEN P.Wrapped = 1 THEN T.[Level]+1 ELSE T.[Level] END AS [Level]
        , @CoilId AS CoilId
        , c.SupplierCoilID
        , CASE WHEN ct.TransactionReason=622 THEN ABS(ct.netquantity) ELSE c.RealNetWeight END AS NetWeight
        , C.RealGrossWeight
        , p1.Description
        , p1.product
        , s.StackID
        , s.ProductID
        , s.Weight
        , P.Product
        , P.Description AS 'ProductDescription'
        , COUNT(t.BlankId) AS 'NumberOfBlanks'
        , c1.Description as 'Status'
        , pv.ProductionWeight
        , pv.BlankWeight
        , t.BlankStatus

FROM @Trace T
    INNER JOIN SKUTraceability SKUT ON SKUT.SKUID = T.SKUID 
    INNER JOIN Stack s ON SKUT.StackID = s.StackID
    INNER JOIN Product p ON s.ProductID = p.ProductID
    INNER JOIN Coil c ON c.CoilID=@CoilId
    INNER JOIN CoilTransaction ct on ct.CoilID=@CoilId
    INNER JOIN Product p1 ON c.ProductID=p1.ProductID
    INNER JOIN Code c1 ON t.BlankStatus=c1.codenumber AND c1.codetypeid=17 
    INNER JOIN @ProductVersion pv ON pv.ProductID=p.ProductId AND s.ProductVersion = pv.ProductVersion

WHERE t.BlankId IS NOT NULL

GROUP BY  T.[Level]
        , c.SupplierCoilID
        , CASE WHEN ct.TransactionReason=622 THEN ABS(ct.netquantity) ELSE c.RealNetWeight END
        , c.RealGrossWeight
        , p1.Description
        , p1.product
        , s.StackID
        , s.ProductID
        , s.Weight
        , p.Product
        , p.Description
        , c1.Description
        , pv.ProductionWeight
        , pv.BlankWeight 
        , p.Wrapped
        , t.BlankStatus
```

Comment: how about you remove the CASE WHEN in the Group by columns and instead replace it with NetWeight column?

Comment: Then it will give me an error about ct.transactionreason and ct.netquantity not being in the GROUP BY or AGGREGATE function.

Comment: You need to add them in the group by or in an aggregate clause. So, if you have different `c.realnetweight` which one should be displayed in your `one row` - the smaller, the biggest or what?

Comment: Personally I think that lines fine.  I think the issue is `t.level` in the group by should be `CASE WHEN P.Wrapped = 1 THEN T.[Level]+1 ELSE T.[Level] END`  your displaying a cased level which is different than what you're grouping by. and the aliased value in the select is not in scope in the group by, so you must use the formula in the group by.

Answer (score 0):

Hard to answer without understanding your table structures however, it appears that `CoilTransaction` is some sort of transaction table, i.e. a single product can have many transactions.

In your `SELECT` query, the line causing you issues, is the only line that references your `CoilTransaction` table therefore I believe, the reason you're returning multiple rows is because you're grouping on a value that is not unique.  Also, are transactions individual items because you seem to have a quantity column on the table.

In short, you can't get the grouping you want by including those columns from your transaction table.  You would need to elaborate more on what you're trying to accomplish for us to give a more suitable solution.  What does that line mean?

Answer (score 0):

For at least one `CoilID` in table `Coil`, you will have more than one value in the field `netquantity` in the table `CoilTransaction`. This is what is causing the increase in the number of records returned when you include this field in your `CASE` statement.

I would recommend finding the `netquantity` value that you want from `CoilTransaction` in a CTE, and then bringing this in to your `CASE` statement. For example:

```
;WITH transaction_summary AS (
 SELECT
  ct.CoilID,
  ct.TransactionReason,
  MAX(ct.netquantity) -- choose your aggregate function here
 FROM
  CoilTransaction ct
 GROUP BY
  ct.CoilID,
  ct.TransactionReason
)
...
```